# Devise- Custom users#new method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

```
def new
     @title = "Create a user"
     @user = User.new
end

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

when i try submit my form to create a new user, i get a message "You are already signed in." and the user does not get created what could be the problem?

Comment: As far as I know you can't use a custom method only, you need to provide a whole custom controller for, i.e. registrations. What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to create users only when you are logged in

Comment: Are they the same kind of user that would already be logged in, or are you talking about sub-accounts, like XBox Live and PS3/PSN in the video game world? At any rate, I think you need to use more words to describe what you want to do.

Comment: Eric: They are the same users, i have fixed it not using Vapire's suggestion, overriding the registration controller ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you have to tell Devise you want to use a custom controller for registrations, so it knows not to use it's default behaviour.

Since you want to restrict users from registering publicly, I think (I didn't test this) you have to create your own custom registrations controller, which does the same thing as devise defaults one, except only if a user is already logged in... I'm not sure though what exactly happens after the (not public) registration is finished. Cause Devise tries to log you in automatically - depending if you're using confirmable or not... But my guess would be that you get logged out as the old user and logged in as the new one...

So to give you directions you should read the README section concerning [Configuring Controllers](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers).
And then you could try simply to add a the before_filter to authenticate a user in your custom registrations controller (assuming your user model is called `User`):

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

But again. I didn't test this... so maybe it's not the way to do it, but it's worth a try :)

Comment: I added before_filter :authenticate_user! to my UsersController but nothing changed, this is where i'm trying to create a new user

Comment: Did you tell Devise to use your UsersController as its RegistrationController in your routes file? Did you do everything that's mentioned in the README?

Comment: devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/new" }

Comment: well... In this config Devise is looking for a registrations controller that's called `Users::NewController` in the directory `controllers/users` You have to supply a whole Controller (= class) not a single method! Read the README!

Comment: So there no way to create a user in its own controller?

Comment: Of course there is. But you have to stick to Devises way of configuring... My explanation refers to using 'your own controller', but you have to write it. If you're asking if you can use an existing controller (which is present in your application for something else than registration) to register a new user, I would say no - but this way isn't recommended anyway...

Comment: PS: you can of course mimic Devises behaviour of registration in one of you own methods - but why would you have to do that if Devise offers you a way to use its mechanisms?

Comment: I don't know whether devise has changed alot since i've last used it but in an older project with an older version of devise i was able to use the users controller somehow might take a look through that